# Selected value from dropdown into PHP variable

Tags: php

I know many people have been asking the same thing, but I don't seem to get anywhere with this. How do I extract the value from my select drop down and put it into a Php variable. I need variable for calling the database later.

This is my select list in html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>STREAM</p>
    <select name="selectStream">
    <?php foreach($array as $option) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option->ID; ?>"><?php echo   $option->stream_name; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="formStream" value="Select"></td>
</form>
```

My result from a mysqli call is already in the $array. I would then like to use the selected value from this form and simply even just echo it. I can get the information from MySQL into the drop down, but getting the selected variable out is a nightmare. I've been trying to capture this with:

```
if(isset($_POST['formStream'])) 
{
  $selected = $_POST['selectedStream'];
  echo "This is what I get: ".$selected;
}
```

I know I can do this by sending the value to an external php, but I would need to have the variable here. Could someone please assist?

Answer (score 3):

Name of your dropdown is `selectStream` not `selectedStream`

This is wrong

```
$selected = $_POST['selectedStream'];
```

it should be

```
$selected = $_POST['selectStream'];
```

Here is the working code

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>STREAM</p>
    <select name="selectStream">

        <option value="1"><1</option>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="formStream" value="Select"></td>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['formStream'])) 
{
  $selected = $_POST['selectStream'];
  echo "This is what I get: ".$selected;// will echo This is what I get: 1
}

?>
```

Comment: Okay, you are right, I changed this. And now it displays: This is what i get: so the variable is empty. Is there anything specific that I have to do on the UI side? I just select something from the list and press the button...

Comment: inspect element and check if are getting values for options.

Comment: @user Start with a `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: ["selectStreams"]=> string(0) I'm sorry, I hardly ever use php so I have no idea, but this is what I get from var_dump. Seem like the variable is just empty..

Comment: @user Update your question with a sample of the actual HTML of your form that's being output.

Comment: Hmm, that is that actual html I've got here. It just runs through the array and puts all values in the <option>.

Comment: are you getting any options in select?

Comment: @user Nope, that's not the actual HTML the browser will see. That's your PHP code that will produce HTML. We need to see what the browser actually sees.

Comment: @user2590369, check the edit... i have added working code.